# Opting for images or video

Tags: html, css, image, video

I am trying to figure out how to display either a image or video in html. To clarify, I want to display video but alternatively if the video is not there or the file is not found I would like a default picture to display instead. Basically an image file to display if the video will not or isn't there. Is this even possible? I've been trying to figure this out for a while. No luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this piece of code, that offers HTML5 video fallback to Flash and Flash fallback to simple Image, without absolutely no javascript involved!

```
<!-- first try HTML5 playback: if serving as XML, expand `controls` to `controls="controls"` and autoplay likewise -->
<!-- warning: playback does not work on iOS3 if you include the poster attribute! fixed in iOS4.0 -->
<video width="100%" height="200px" controls>

    <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.MP4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video    -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.OGV" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->

    <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">

         <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
         <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
         <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />

         <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
         <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
         title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>

<!-- you *must* offer a download link as they may be able to play the file locally. customise this bit all you want -->
<p>    
     <strong>Download Video:</strong>
     Closed Format: <a href="__VIDEO__.MP4">"MP4"</a>
     Open Format:   <a href="__VIDEO__.OGV">"Ogg"</a>
</p>​
```